# Redirect subfolder content to different domain with htaccess (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I'm trying to redirect all the content from `domain.com/subfolder` to `newdomain.com`.

Currently using this in `.htaccess` on `domain.com/subfolder`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/$ http://newdomain.com/
```

The problem is it only works with `http://newdomain.com/`, but when browsing ex. `http://newdomain.com/page1` a 500 error pops up.

Also tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com\subfolder$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com./$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com\subfolder$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code produces:

> newdomain.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your
>   cookies.

Both domains belong to the same account.

Comment: Yes, both domains belong to the same account. Tried different browsers and still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... both domains belong to the same account.

You'll need to use mod_rewrite in that case, since you can't differentiate domains/hosts with mod_alias (ie. `RedirectMatch`). Also, note that 301 redirects will be cached by the browser, so it's quite possible that the browser has cached your earlier (erroneous) attempts.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com\subfolder$
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the *host* (or domain) part of the URL. This does not include the `subfolder`. (But you've also used a backslash as a path separator and have an erroneous dot in the substitution.)

Try the following in the `domain.com/subfolder/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. As mentioned above, 301s are cached, 302s are not, so it makes testing easier.

Comment: Worked like a charm, very much appreciated.